# ImageView and TextView not being set on Activity creation

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm trying to display an image and a some strings on my activity, but for some reason the views are not being modified.

This is my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ObjectProperty extends Activity {


    Activity myAct = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myAct = this;
        setContentView(R.layout.object_property);

        String objetoNome = myAct.getIntent().getStringExtra("nome");
        String arquivo = myAct.getIntent().getStringExtra("arquivo");
        String descricao = myAct.getIntent().getStringExtra("descricaoCompleta");

        System.out.println("objeto nome: " + objetoNome); //not null/empty
        System.out.println("arquivo: " + arquivo);        //not null/empty
        System.out.println("descricao: " + descricao);    //not null/empty

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.item_image);
        TextView textViewNome = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.item_nome);
        TextView textViewDescricao = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.item_desc);    

        textViewNome.setText(objetoNome); //does not set text
        textViewDescricao.setText(descricao); //does not set text

        if(!arquivo.equals("")){

            Bitmap myBit = getThumbnail(arquivo);

            if(myBit != null)
                imageView.setImageBitmap(myBit); // does not set image
        }

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.object_property);
    }

    public Bitmap getThumbnail(String filename) 
    {
        Bitmap thumbnail = null;

        try {
            File filePath = myAct.getFileStreamPath(filename);
            FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(filePath);
            thumbnail = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fi);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return thumbnail;
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove this

```
setContentView(R.layout.object_property);
```

from the last part of onCreate.

Answer (score 0):

Call to super class method `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` must be in the first line of oncreate() method.

Remove the last line `setContentView(R.layout.object_property);` in oncreate() method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, call setConteinView only one time.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //your code
}
```

Comment: what's the point into giving an answer that was already given? : \